# CodeIgniter 3 - Accessing data in a view from 2 db's

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Apologies for my nebie like question but i'm trying to learn a lot here, new to MVC and CodeIgniter.

I have a simple CRUD that i'm building, but i'm stumped on what I think is a very simple thing if you know what you are doing.

I have a View that is being used to Update a Tyre to the db into a table 'tyres'. In that View I want to display a dropdown of Brands that are held in a seperate db table 'brands'. In my Model I have a class of Tyres and in that I have a function :

```
public function get_tyres($id = FALSE)
{
if ($id === FALSE)
{
    $query = $this->db->get('tyres');
    return $query->result_array();
}
$query = $this->db->get_where('tyres', array('id' => $id));
return $query->row_array();
}
```

This allows me to access the Tyres data in my Controller and send the data through to the View using :

```
$data['tyres_item'] = $this->tyres_model->get_tyres($id);
$this->load->view('tyres/update', $data);
```

In my View I access the $data['tyres_item'] so that I can prefill the form with db data.

BUT

How do I access the Brands data from the db to build a dropdown list of all Brands in my view? 
I have separate Model and Controller for Brands but I can't access them in the View.

I tried adding

```
$data['brands'] = $this->brands_model->get_brands();
```

to my update function in my Tyre Controller but i understand that this won;t work because I am inside the Tyres Controller and not the Brands Controller.

How can I accomplish this, I know I must be missing something straightforward...

Here's my View : and what I want to accomplish :

```
     echo form_open('tyres/update');
    ?>

    <label for="tyre">Tyre</label>
    <input type="input" name="tyre"  value="<?=$tyres_item['tyre']?>" />

    <label for="brand">Brand</label>
<?php
    echo form_dropdown('brands', $data['brands']);
?>
```

...

EDIT- I've added the brands model to the construct and that has helped, I can now access the brands data in my view using :

```
echo form_dropdown('brands', $brands);
```

But it returns an array so I added the following :

```
echo form_dropdown('brands', $brands['brand']);
```

This then errors out with :

```
Message: Undefined index: brand
```

I'm stuck AGAIN!
Help.

Comment: Use `echo form_dropdown('brands', $brands['COLUMN_NAME']);`

Comment: Thanks for that, I've tried it though and i'm getting :

Undefined variable: brands

Answer (score 1):

Got It!

I needed to loop through the db result then add that to the form_dropdown :

```
foreach($brands as $brand)
    {
            $brand_list[$brand['id']] = ucfirst(htmlspecialchars($brand['brand']));
    } 

echo form_dropdown('brands', $brand_list, $tyres_item['brand']);
```

This might help someone.